# How can you stack buttons on top of each other in Manifest XML

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to create a group that has buttons stacked on top of each other like in this picture. [This exists in already in the Home Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyZOm.png)

From what I can see from the documentation, these are defined by the Control type element which has three different types: Button, Menu, and MobileButton. Button and Menu create one of the bigger buttons while MobileButton only works for MobileFormFactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not supported with the office web add-in manifests. You could achieve this using [COM addins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/office-com-add-in-using-visual-c).

You can see office web add-in commands details here, these are the modern javascript add-ins: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/design/add-in-commands.md

As it stands in the manifest options today, you can't change the size of the button or stack them. It's a standard button which you can use it as a regular Button or a Menu.

Comment: When you said "web" add-in, were you referring to Office on the Web? I am developing for Windows Office, would this be possible for that version?

Comment: No, web addins are the addins that leverage office.js and are cross platform (if you are using html and js to write it, it will be cross platform) COM addins are windows only

Comment: This is one of many major Office.js deficiencies that must be addressed before devs can build useful add-ins with it.  I have confirmed this answer at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-6-add-extensionpoint-elements ("Currently, only buttons and menus are supported").  Also, buttons unfortunately do not have size element or property to determine whether they are large or small as with Custom IU XML.

Comment: @HarshPatel If you're developing specifically for Windows, then it would be possible to create the COM Add-ins Mavi mentions in the answer. The Visual Studio tool for this is VSTO, but there are also others (not free). It's also possible to "roll your own" by implementing the IDT2Extensbility interface provided by MIcrosoft for the Office applications (also free - all the tools do this).

Answer (score 1):

That would be a new feature ask for dynamic ribbon for JS add-in, and I would suggest that you could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563. and upvote for this feature. therefore we could prioritize it based on the vote. thanks for your support